# How to add Top Padding in my textField (Objective-c)

Tags: ios, objective-c, textfield, padding

I have textField, CustomClass.

But I don't know how to use Insets. I know functions but don't know how to use them.

[image: Notes textField]

Answer (score 0):

Use this method in your customClass

```
- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
        return CGRectMake(bounds.origin.x + yourPading, bounds.origin.y + yourPading,
                          bounds.size.width - yourPading, bounds.size.height - yourPading);
    }
    - (CGRect)editingRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
        return [self textRectForBounds:bounds];
    }
```